# Windows 10 Photos app will not display photos in subfolders

Tags: windows-10, photos, app

I have a folder with photos organized in subfolders. I go to Folders, click "add folder", select this folder and it's internal structure shows in the sidebar. Clicking on any of the subfolders that appear on the side bar won't show any of the pictures, though, even if they're full of pictures in valid formats (jpg, heic, png, etc).

I only get this message:

> ### Browse subfolders or add photos here
>
> You have no photos in this folder. You can check your subfolders
> for photos, or drag and drop photos to this folder.

There's only one folder where some of the pictures will show up (not all of them), but I can't find anything special on it. Even permissions and ownership are the same.

The "legacy" Photos app shows content normally, though.

Comment: Anything different about subfolder names where the app *does* work, and where it *does not*, such as spaces in the folder or file names?